# Resized image locked file

Tags: c#, image, image-resizing

This is my code to resize an image. It works fine but when I try to delete the previously created, I have an error "file is used by another process". This is the code:

```
try
{
    int newHeight = width * fromStream.Height / fromStream.Width;

    Image newImage = new Bitmap(width, newHeight);
    using (Graphics graphicsHandle = Graphics.FromImage(newImage))
    {
        graphicsHandle.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
        graphicsHandle.DrawImage(fromStream, 0, 0, width, newHeight);
    }
    string processedFileName = String.Concat(Configuration.CoverLocalPath, @"\Processed\res_", Path.GetFileName(imageFile));
    newImage.Save(processedFileName, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    newImage.Dispose();

    return processedFileName;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Configuration.Log.Debug("Utility.cs", "ResizeMainCover", ex.Message);
    return string.Empty;
}
```

I tried to dispose the Image object but without success. Any hints?

Comment: you might have the output open in some viewer ...

Comment: In fact that image is inside a datagridView cell ...

Answer (score 1):

Without more code, its hard to tell, but more than likely the culprit is your `fromStream` not being closed and disposed properly. I'm assuming "previously created" means your source stream. Try wrapping it in a `using` statement, note I also wrapped the newImage so it would be disposed properly in case of an Exception.

```
using(var fromStream = GetSourceImageStream()) 
{ 
    try 
    {
      int newHeight = width * fromStream.Height / fromStream.Width;

      using(Image newImage = new Bitmap(width, newHeight))
      {
        using (Graphics graphicsHandle = Graphics.FromImage(newImage))
        {
          graphicsHandle.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
          graphicsHandle.DrawImage(fromStream, 0, 0, width, newHeight);
        }
        string processedFileName = String.Concat(Configuration.CoverLocalPath, @"\Processed\res_", Path.GetFileName(imageFile));
        newImage.Save(processedFileName, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
      }    
      return processedFileName; 
    } 
    catch (Exception ex) 
    {
       Configuration.Log.Debug("Utility.cs", "ResizeMainCover", ex.Message);
       return string.Empty; 
    }
    finally
    {
      fromStream.Close();
    } 
 }
```